# Should I de-mean a predictor variable before a dummy interaction

Tags: multiple-regression, forecasting, multicollinearity, standardization, centering

Suppose I have the following time-series linear model where $\beta$ is misspecified:

$Y(t+1) = \alpha + \beta X(t) + \sum_{i=1}^{10000}\gamma_i Z_i(T) + \varepsilon$

where all parameters are in $\mathbb{R}$ and all predictors are normally distributed and play nicely with respect to Gauss Markov.

In the population ('correct') model that corresponds to the above, the slope parameter on $X(t)$ is equal to $\beta_1$ when $X(t) > \text{Q}_{0.95}(X(t))$ and is equal to $\beta_2$ when $X(t) < \text{Q}_{0.95}(X(t))$, where $Q$ is the quantile function. This break in parameters is a priori knowledge. We also have that $\beta_1 \neq \beta_2$.

I want to model this as follows:

$Y(t+1) = \alpha + \beta_1 X(t)I(X(t) > Q_{0.95}(X(t))) $

$+ \beta_2 X(t)I(X(t) < Q_{0.95}(X(t)))$

$+ \sum_{i=1}^{10000}\gamma_i Z_i(T)  + \varepsilon$

My **question** is whether it is good practice to de-mean $X(t)$ before estimating the equation with the indicator function breaks, supposing my objective is out of sample forecast accuracy? I ask because this has an effect on collinearity between predictors (which could impact some, but not all, feature selection algorithms). Note that feature selection and regularisation is done in an automated way.

I do not care about standard errors.